# nginx always shows the default page

Tags: nginx

i set up a nginx webserver with some virtual hosts and a default host (with return 444;) for all unmatched connections.

If i try to visit one of my virtual hosts, i still get the 444.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;


        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        upstream php-handler {
                server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        server_tokens off;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  listen     443 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 444;
  access_log off; log_not_found off;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name <mydomain.com>;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name <mydomain.com>;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/acme.sh/<....>/fullchain.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/acme.sh/<....>/<...>.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://....:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      client_max_body_size 0;
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to get it working?
btw: if i delete the default one, i can access my virtual host.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you get redirected from http to https before the 444?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yep

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got the solution.

I forgot to define the ssl certificate in my default file.
After i added a self-signed certificate it works.